# Wordpress Site Broken After Updating Theme

Tags: nginx, wordpress, fastcgi

If I leave out needed details, please tell me.
I'm running Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I use php5-fpm.

Currently I am battling with my PHP installation, and it's causing a couple problems now. See my other problem here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/695592/wordpress-502-bad-gateway

**The problem:** Site was working fine. I updated my theme. Now, when I load the website, or any part of it (e.g. wp-admin, wp-login, index.php) I simply get a white, blank page in my browser.

Here is what I captured from the /var/log/nginx/error.log file when I try to load the website.

```
2015/06/01 22:12:38 [error] 2054#0: *2 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/usr/share/nginx/flarefox_services/tech/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/inc/accesspress-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/nginx/flarefox_services/tech/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/functions.php on line 192
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/nginx/flarefox_services/tech/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/inc/accesspress-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /usr/share/nginx/flarefox_services/tech/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax/functions.php on line 192" while reading response header from upstream, client: 199.27.128.71, server: tech.flarefox.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "tech.flarefox.com"
```

<strike>Very familiar to my other problem, it's an issue with FastCGI, I believe.</strike> However, I see too that the theme isn't able to find resources it needs. I can't find them either.

**Edit:** Am I going crazy? Or did the update delete all of the theme's essential files?

```
root@Domains:::/usr/share/nginx/flarefox_services/tech/wp-content/themes/accesspress-parallax
>> ll
total 708
drwxr-xr-x 5 wptech wptech   4096 Jun  1 21:53 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 root   root     4096 Jun  1 22:27 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech    604 Jun  1 21:53 404.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   1136 Jun  1 21:53 content-none.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   2934 Jun  1 21:53 content.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   2145 Jun  1 21:53 content-search.php
drwxr-xr-x 4 wptech wptech   4096 Jun  1 21:53 css/
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   9502 Jun  1 21:53 functions.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   2658 Jun  1 21:53 home-page.php
drwxr-xr-x 3 wptech wptech   4096 Jun  1 21:53 images/
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   2892 Jun  1 21:53 index-parallax.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   1391 Jun  1 21:53 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 wptech wptech   4096 Jun  1 21:53 layouts/
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech  35146 Jun  1 21:53 license.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   1250 Jun  1 21:53 page.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech 569921 Jun  1 21:53 screenshot.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech   1121 Jun  1 21:53 search.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech    288 Jun  1 21:53 sidebar.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 wptech wptech  39192 Jun  1 21:53 style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the theme again from the developer, and I uploaded the theme files to my server, not overwriting existing files, and it fixed it.

How my files vanished is truly a mystery.